# Passing dynamic data from controller to a view with a defined script that uses that dynamic data to load a php view

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I am new to MVC and working on a **video calling facility** between two parties where an admin schedules a call between two the two parties and stores the randomly generated room number in a table.

Okay some background first, there are some **patients** and a **doctor**. An admin schedules a call between them. Whenever a patient or a doctor clicks on video call first an ajax query calls a function and checks if there is an entry for the patient/doctor using their id's in the schedule table and if it's there it calls the video chat view.

So to set up video calling I have used a script in the views page which randomly generates a room number(Here I need to get that room number from the table and not generate a random one). I need some help here. I just cannot call the webpage directly using the controller without passing the room number.

I have tried passing the room number to the controller but doesn't seem to work and I am completely confused on how to execute it because of the way how php webpages work
Any help would be appreciated.

1st - This is my view page for the patient where the ajax method checks if there's an entry and then opens the window for video chat

```php
 $(document).on('click','#create_call', function(){

    var case_id=$(this).attr('class');
    $('#case_id_get').val(case_id);

    $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url('video/checkpatient');?>",
            type: "post",
            data: {case_id:case_id},
            success: function(response)
            {
                if(response==1)
                {
                    var newwindow = window.open('video/videochat');
                }
                else
                {
                    Messenger().post({
                        message: 'NO ENTRY FOUND',
                        type: 'error',
                        showCloseButton: true
                    });
                }
            }
        });


    });
```

`video` is my controller and `checkpatient` and `videochat` are its functions. Here's the controller within the functions

```php
    public function videochat()
    {

            $views = array('video/webcam.php');
            $data = array('views'=>$views);
            $this->load->view('template/main',$data);
    }

    public function checkpatient()
    {
        $case_id = $this->input->post('case_id');
        $checkentry = $this->Call_Schedule->CheckPatientEntry($case_id);
        if($checkentry->num_rows()>0)
        {
            echo '1';
            exit;
        }
        echo '0';

    }
```

As you can see when I call `videochat` it opens a page named `webcam.php` which contains my script to start call.

```html
<style>
    video {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
  transform: scaleX(-1);
  }
  </style> 
  <div>
    <video id="localVideo" autoplay></video>
    <video id="remoteVideo" autoplay></video>
  </div>
<script>



hash = Math.floor(Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF).toString(16); 
const roomnumber = hash;
// Here I want the roomnumber to be used from the table not use the randomly generated number.

// other code to run the video call
```

How do I get the room number from the table corresponding to a patient/doctor?

Comment: is case_id not getting to   public function checkpatient() this function ?? is that that the only  problem you are facing ,, so if you try to print case id in checkatient() its not happening ?

Comment: @sumit I am having no issues with checkpatient() function. Here I am getting the case id from the input->post method. I need some help to use room number in the webcam.php script from the database

Answer (score 0):

Here  You Have passed `echo '1'`  which is string  but in response u have checked `response == 1` which is int

in controller

```
public function checkpatient()
    {
        $case_id = $this->input->post('case_id');
        $checkentry = $this->Call_Schedule->CheckPatientEntry($case_id);
        if($checkentry->num_rows()>0)
        {
            echo '1';  // change to '1' to 1  string to int 
            exit;
        }
        echo '0';

    }
```

In Script

```
$.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url('video/checkpatient');?>",
            type: "post",
            data: {case_id:case_id},
            success: function(response)
            {
                if(parseInt(response)==1) // change from stringt  to  int 
                {
                    var newwindow = window.open('video/videochat');
                }
                else
                {
                    Messenger().post({
                        message: 'NO ENTRY FOUND',
                        type: 'error',
                        showCloseButton: true
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

If this is not the cause please clarify that if case id is being printed in checkpatient() function or not

Comment: I am having no issues in calling the window.open(video/videochat) function. It's working fine for me. I need to pass a new variable room number to the newwindow variable and then use this variable in the webcam.php script function.

Comment: window.location.href="<?php echo base_url()?>/video/videochat?random= "+roomnuber;                                                             cant u send randomnubmer through get method and get it in videochat() function ? or am i missing something